# /etc/fstab doesn't show temp but temp is mounted. CentOS 7 on linode

Tags: centos7, linode, fstab

In CentOS 7, I have been told to secure the /tmp folder with with noexec,nosuid in /etc/fstab

When I view the /etc/fstab, I can only see few lines without /tmp mounting option.

I have created a tmp disk (1gb) and assign this disk via linode manager to /dev/sdc

and in order to mount this in /etc/fstab

I write the following:

/dev/sdc /tmp  ext4    defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec 0 0
then I save this and reboot the server.

I test my /tmp folder by downloading something using wget but nothing got saved in the folder.

How do I secure the /tmp folder in /tmp and /var/tmp?

I read that I must create a new drive for /tmp in order for it to be able to mount as nosuid and noexec

Can anyone guide me? I'm new to CentOS 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `/lib/systemd/system/tmp.mount`. See the `systemd(1)`, `systemd.unit(5)`, and `systemd.mount(5)` man pages for more details.

Comment: I don't understand this.. sorry. do you mean that the mounting done by the system?.. I'm lost now.. I just want to know how do I secure the /tmp folder in /tmp and /var/tmp in CentOS 7 at linode.

Comment: Yes, systemd is responsible for mounting it. The options are controlled by that unit file.

Comment: Ok, how do I secure the /tmp folder with nosuid,noexec ? I have to install directadmin and the requirements said I have to mount the /tmp folder with nosuid and noexec. So far that I know, I have to create a partition for this. https://www.directadmin.com/install.php

Comment: Have you had a chance to inspect the file and man pages?

Comment: What is the bracket number referring too? example systemd (1) ?

Comment: The section the man page belongs to. `man 1 man`

Comment: Ok in the /lib/systemd/system/tmp.mount I see the following:   
[Mount]
What=tmpfs
Where=/tmp
Type=tmpfs
Options=mode=1777,strictatime

So adding nosuid,noexec at the Options will work for this?

Comment: I'm about to accept this answer, But I dont understand how can the system mount the /temp folder without creating a new partition (as what I read, we need to create partition to be able to mount as nosuid and noexec? Can you explain the concept in your answer?

Comment: `tmpfs` is an in-memory filesystem.

Comment: So, meaning that. My temporary file is using RAM instead of hard drive? I got it.. So it will clear itself when I reboot the server? Is what I'm doing above is correct? extending an option nosuid and noexec?

Comment: "Options=
           Mount options to use when mounting. This takes a comma-separated
           list of options."